# Unable to run standalone test script in Selenium with Python

Tags: selenium2, python

So, I have the latest Selenium 2.0 Python bindings installed via pip (Python 2.7.2, Windows 7).

I wrote a small script to see if I could get it working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.close()
```

This will run, and open the command line. Then, a blank vanilla instance of Firefox 5.0 will launch, with "WebDriver" in the bottom right status bar. The command-line client will then terminate, and the Firefox window will persist. The specified URL does not open, and nor does the browser close afterwards. It just waits there.

I am however, behind a proxy when testing this, so I must admit I haven't tried it outside of the proxy. But, with this in mind, I thought to update my code with new profile information:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.xx.xxx.xxx")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.close()
```

This was based on the issue found here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2061

Again, the same behaviour as before. Does anyone have some pointers on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Try typing it in to the Python interpreter, see what happens. Try other URLs besides google. Also, do you get the same results with IE?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. Tried a similar code outside the proxy and it ran without problems.

I found googling that you need to open Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) before running the coded and then browsers stay and can get to the line `driver.get(some url)` - I couldn't previously -. But then, when getting an URL, a display is shown for Proxy Authentication and I can not pass through it.

I have being googling and can not find a solution to this problem, but hope the Fiddler ¿solution? can help you in the very beggining.

Comment: I actually solved this, it is definitely a proxy problem- I was using Windows, and I needed to define the proxy in the OS-wide settings, not just the browser.

Comment: @persopolis If you solved the problem, perhaps you could add an answer describing what you did, and then you could check it as "the best answer".